# Unable to login to FB via fbchat in python [2FA not enabled]

Tags: python, python-3.x, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

I'm trying to login using [fbchat](https://github.com/fbchat-dev/fbchat) a python package. `2FA` is **DISABLED** for the account I'm using yet it is showing this exception.

I have check the following, but not working:

- [Unable to login to facebook using fbchat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64646306/unable-to-login-to-facebook-using-fbchat)
- [Python fbchat - Login failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41399539/python-fbchat-login-failed)

#### ⚠ Exception

```dart
Attempt #1 failed, retrying
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Hamza\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\fbchat\_client.py", line 209, in login
    user_agent=user_agent,
  File "C:\Users\Hamza\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\fbchat\_state.py", line 155, in login
    "(Failed on url: {})".format(r.url)
fbchat._exception.FBchatUserError: Login failed. Check email/password. (Failed on url: https://m.facebook.com/zero/policy/optin?_rdc=1&_rdr#_=_)
```

Comment: Using such tools to directly interact with the website UI is against Facebook’s ToS to begin with.

Comment: I'm sorry didn't know but everyone is doing it I just tried to work. Thanks for the info sir :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the URL is failing. Going off the given location, I'd say FB has closed that door.

You could ask the `python fbchat` author directly, but that project is no longer maintained. Probably because FB is preventing it as per their ToS.

But really, I don't think anyone needs another FB bot annoying them. Please stahp.